# sum of total values PL/Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to fetch a PLSQL statement to display all the list of customer ID and the sum of order value for each customer. the following code gets me the correct answer but the issue is that I have multiple customers with the same ID and I need to sum all their order values under only 1 ID  output and not multiple.my code gets me multiple output for the same customer.

```
  Create table sales (customer_ID number(10), product_ID number(10), quantity number(10));

INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(3,1,23);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(1,2,34);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(1,3,654);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(3,7,32);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(4,3,23);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(3,3,111);
INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(5,4,6);




Create table products (product_ID number(10), price number(10));
INSERT INTO products (product_ID, price) Values(1,32);
INSERT INTO products (product_ID, price) Values(2,121);
INSERT INTO products (product_ID, price) Values(3,3000);
INSERT INTO products (product_ID, price) Values(4,621);
INSERT INTO products (product_ID, price) Values(5,363);
INSERT INTO products (product_ID, price) Values(6,32);
INSERT INTO products (product_ID, price) Values(7,3);
INSERT INTO products (product_ID, price) Values(8,432);
INSERT INTO products (product_ID, price) Values(9,11);
INSERT INTO products (product_ID, price) Values(10,73);


declare
cursor cur is select unique sales.quantity,products.price,sales.customer_ID
from sales,products
where sales.product_id=products.product_id
order by customer_ID desc;
prod number;
quan number(10);
pri number(10);
c_id number(10);
begin
open cur;
loop
fetch cur into quan,pri,c_id;
exit when cur%notfound;
prod:=pri*quan;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('customer_id =' || c_id);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('quantity value =' || quan);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('price =' || pri);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The total value of customer purchases is = ' || prod);
end loop;
close cur;
END
```

please adivse.

Comment: Please provide the create table statement, and make sure you add the INSERT into table_name clause tot he insert statements. And, do you really need to use `PL/SQL`? It could be done in plain `SQL`. PL/SQL `LOOP`, `row-by-row` a.k.a. `slow-by-slow`.

Comment: changes done and yes I need to get it by pl/sql ,, the code is ready I just need the sum of the same customer ids under 1 output

Comment: What is the output you're expecting, and why do you "have" to do it in PL/SQL? Please update your question with the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use **SUM** as aggregate function using **GROUP BY**.

Using **PL/SQL**

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    CURSOR cur
  3    IS
  4      SELECT SUM(sales.quantity),
  5        SUM(products.price),
  6        sales.customer_ID
  7      FROM sales,
  8        products
  9      WHERE sales.product_id=products.product_id
 10      GROUP BY customer_ID
 11      ORDER BY customer_ID DESC;
 12    prod NUMBER;
 13    quan NUMBER(10);
 14    pri  NUMBER(10);
 15    c_id NUMBER(10);
 16  BEGIN
 17    OPEN cur;
 18    LOOP
 19      FETCH cur INTO quan,pri,c_id;
 20      EXIT
 21    WHEN cur%notfound;
 22      prod:=pri*quan;
 23      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('customer_id =' || c_id);
 24      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('quantity value =' || quan);
 25      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('price =' || pri);
 26      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The total value of customer purchases is = ' || prod);
 27    END LOOP;
 28    CLOSE cur;
 29  END;
 30  /
customer_id =5
quantity value =6
price =621
The total value of customer purchases is = 3726
customer_id =4
quantity value =23
price =3000
The total value of customer purchases is = 69000
customer_id =3
quantity value =166
price =3035
The total value of customer purchases is = 503810
customer_id =1
quantity value =688
price =3121
The total value of customer purchases is = 2147248

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

By the way, the whole **PL/SQL** block could be written in pure **SQL**.

Using **SQL**

```
SQL> SELECT SUM(sales.quantity) AS "quantity",
  2    SUM(products.price) AS "price",
  3    sales.customer_ID
  4  FROM sales,
  5    products
  6  WHERE sales.product_id=products.product_id
  7  GROUP BY customer_ID
  8  ORDER BY customer_ID DESC;

  quantity      price CUSTOMER_ID
---------- ---------- -----------
         6        621           5
        23       3000           4
       166       3035           3
       688       3121           1

SQL>
```

**Update** OP wants to filter the rows based on user input.

In **SQL*Plus**, you could declare a variable and use it in the filter predicate:

```
SQL> variable cust_id NUMBER
SQL> EXEC :cust_id:= 4

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

No,let's use the above **variable** in the filter predicate:

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    CURSOR cur
  3    IS
  4      SELECT SUM(sales.quantity),
  5        SUM(products.price),
  6        sales.customer_ID
  7      FROM sales,
  8        products
  9      WHERE sales.product_id=products.product_id
 10      AND sales.customer_ID = :cust_id
 11      GROUP BY customer_ID
 12      ORDER BY customer_ID DESC;
 13    prod NUMBER;
 14    quan NUMBER(10);
 15    pri  NUMBER(10);
 16    c_id NUMBER(10);
 17  BEGIN
 18    OPEN cur;
 19    LOOP
 20      FETCH cur INTO quan,pri,c_id;
 21      EXIT
 22    WHEN cur%notfound;
 23      prod:=pri*quan;
 24      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('customer_id =' || c_id);
 25      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('quantity value =' || quan);
 26      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('price =' || pri);
 27      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The total value of customer purchases is = ' || prod);
 28    END LOOP;
 29    CLOSE cur;
 30  END;
 31  /
customer_id =4
quantity value =23
price =3000
The total value of customer purchases is = 69000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

If you want to do this from a front-end application, you could put the entire logic in a **PROCEDURE** and accept the `customer_id` as **IN parameter**. And use it in the filter predicate.

Comment: Thank you very much.. one last question, How can I enable an end user to type in the customer ID and the output would be for that ID entered?

Comment: Then you need to use Procedure to have INPUT parameters. Then use this input parameter as **bind variable** in the predicate to filter the rows. Or, in SQL*Plus, you could use **substitution variable** for the SQL.

Comment: @Shak Please mark it as answered, would help others.

Comment: I really dont know how to use that .. I tried with this statement but dont know how to make it fit in the code 
FOR customer_id IN (SELECT product_id  FROM sales  where customer_id=&Customer ID )

will you help me in that please @Lalit Kumar B

Comment: Please advice on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385608/update-table-pl-sql?noredirect=1#comment50748585_31385608

Comment: @Shak Ok, but what about this question?

Comment: This question is done.. Thanks you very much for your efforts. will you please advice on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385608/update-table-pl-sql?noredirect=1#comment50748585_31385608

Comment: @Shak This topic would ONLY be complete if you accept it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry I'm new here and I dont know what do you mean by accept an answer,, lead me how and I'll accept it as an answer

Comment: okay done .. will you help me now in that question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385608/update-table-pl-sql?noredirect=1#comment50748585_31385608

Comment: @Shak I see people have already answered. By the way, are you the same user in that question? You use two logins?

Comment: No i'm not but that question is similar to one I need help in

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID
     ,SUM(QUANTITY) as Total_Quantity
     ,SUM(QUANTITY*PRICE) as Total_Price
FROM
SALES s INNER JOIN
PRODUCTS p on p.PRODUCT_ID=s.PRODUCT_ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID   // Group By each customer Id.
```

Comment: Please advice on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385608/update-table-pl-sql?noredirect=1#comment50748585_31385608

Comment: sorry I'm new here and I dont know what do you mean by accepting the answer.. Thanks

Comment: You need to click `Tick` mark associated with the answer below ,which will become green and that will indicate It was helpful for you. So that, next time, if somebody faces same problem, then they simply look for accepted answer. Please go through this link to understand http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Also, You can not accept multiple answers. :) You have to select only one answer. The answer, you have selected will turn into green other will be considered as non-accepted

Comment: okay done .. will you help me now in that question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385608/update-table-pl-sql?noredirect=1#comment50748585_31385608

Comment: will keep that in mind next time .. will you help me in that question please?

Answer (score 0):

You may use sum() function i.e. something like select sum(sales.quantity) instead of sales-quantity. This will give you the total quantity for that customer_id

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
```

// declaring the variable's

```
a   NUMBER;
b  NUMBER;
Cal NUMBER;

PROCEDURE calcul (a IN NUMBER,b     IN NUMBER,Cal   OUT NUMBER)IS
```

// checking IF condition if a not equal to b , then it will add a and B
       BEGIN

```
        IF a <> b THEN
            Cal := a + b;
        END IF;
  END;
```

// Passing the values to a and b then calling the calcul procedure will do addition.

```
   BEGIN
    a := 10;
    b := 15;
    calcul(a,b,Cal);
    dbms_output.put_line('Sum is ' || Cal);
   END;
```

Comment: Please edit to include a small comment explaining how this code works.