# update table pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to update the following table using pl/sql function, the thing is I managed to write a trigger code but I want to re-write it using 'function' instead.
I would like for Customer 5 to increase their order from 30 to 200. and Enable the user to type in:

1) The number 5 for customer_ID and 
2) 200 for the updated quantity. 
 and print out the total quantity for customer 5 before and after the update.

```
    Create table sales (customer_ID number(10), product_ID number(10), quantity number(10));

    INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(3,1,23);
    INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(1,2,34);
    INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(1,3,654);
    INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(3,7,32);
    INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(4,3,23);
    INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(3,3,111);
    INSERT INTO sales (customer_ID, product_ID, quantity) Values(5,4,6);
```

Trigger code I wrote:

```
create or replace trigger quantity_change 
before insert or update of quantity on sales
for each row
WHEN (NEW.customer_id > 0)
DECLARE
   qua number;
BEGIN
   qua := :NEW.quantity - :OLD.quantity;
   dbms_output.put_line('Old quangtity: ' || :OLD.quantity);
   dbms_output.put_line('New quantity: ' || :NEW.quantity);
   dbms_output.put_line('diiference quangtity: ' || qua);
END;

UPDATE sales
SET quantity = 200 WHERE customer_id = 5;
```

I managed to write this procedure but still stuck, dont know how to enable use

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE Updatesales
( 
customer_ID number,
product_ID number,
quantity number)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE sales
SET quantity= 100
WHERE customer_id= 4;
END;
```

I want to use a function to solve the issue , a function would be somthing like this

```
    CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION function_name [(parameter_name [IN | OUT | IN OUT] type [, ...])]
 RETURN return_datatype {IS | AS} BEGIN < function_body > END [function_name];
```

Please advice

Comment: Why? What is the purpose behind your requirement?

Comment: more knowledge in functions

Comment: So this is a self-knowledge exercise to learn about functions? First off, if I were you, I'd try writing such a function. You'd have to decide what input and output parameters you require and then think about how you might use the parameters to find, update and return the relevant values. Give it a try and update your question with what you've got so far, if you get stuck or have further questions. We can then give you more helpful pointers.

Comment: @Chaz what's the issue ?

Comment: I need to write a function to update a row by enabling a user to input values and get the output before and after the change.. check my last update on the question, I tried to use procedure here

Comment: your trigger looks fine to me. What's the problem ? :s

Comment: the thing is that I dont want to use trigger to solve this question.. I want to solve it using 'function', there is a difference between both, sth like this
CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION function_name [(parameter_name [IN | OUT | IN OUT] type [, ...])] RETURN return_datatype {IS | AS} BEGIN < function_body > END [function_name];

Comment: oracle doesn't support `DML` operations in function.

Comment: check this link .. this what I need to solve the issue using http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_functions.htm

Comment: @jWeaver That is true if calling the function from a _SQL_ statement (such as a `select` or `insert`), unless the function is declared as `pragma autonomous_transaction` (although I would not necessarily recommend doing this). A function called in a PL/SQL block can execute DML.

Comment: Why do you want a function rather than a procedure? You'd need to call it from PL/SQL anyway to make any data changes (i.e. update), rather than as part of a select statement.

Comment: anyone would help in writing a function code please?

Comment: The only difference between a PROCEDURE and a FUNCTION is that a FUNCTION returns a value to the caller while a PROCEDURE does not. That's the difference. If your code needs to return a value you should use a FUNCTION. Otherwise, use a PROCEDURE.

Comment: I need to return 2 values.. any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure isn't using the parameters you have declared; the body should be more like:

```
UPDATE sales
SET quantity= quantity
WHERE customer_id= customer_id;
```

... but that won't do what you expect because you've used the same names for the parameters and columns (and haven't referenced the product ID at all), so every row in the table will be updated with its current value. It's common to use a prefix for your formal parameter names to avoid that confusion, though you can also use the procedure name explicitly when you refer to them.

You said you want a function but it isn't clear why. It's conventional to modify data in procedures and not in functions, and if a function does do any DML then it can't be called from a query and would have to be called in a PL/SQL context. So I'll start with a procedure.

You said you wanted to 'print out' the quantity before and after the update. The procedure shouldn't do that; you should not assume that the user or client can handle dbms_output or will have it enabled. You could use an OUT parameter to return the pre-update value to the caller though:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_sales
( 
  p_customer_id IN sales.customer_id%type,
  p_product_id IN sales.product_id%type,
  p_new_quantity IN sales.quantity%type,
  p_old_quantity OUT sales.quantity%type
) AS
BEGIN
  SELECT quantity
  INTO p_old_quantity
  FROM sales
  WHERE customer_id = p_customer_id
  AND product_id = p_product_id
  FOR UPDATE;

  UPDATE sales
  SET quantity = p_new_quantity
  WHERE customer_id = p_customer_id
  AND product_id = p_product_id;
END;
/
```

This gets the current value of the quantity into an OUT variable, and also locks the record with `for update` to stop the value changing while you're working on it (probably overkill here, but you want to learn...)

It then updates the same row with the new value that was passed in. That is finding the row again using the customer and product IDs, and you could do that differently if you want to experiment - get the rowid into another local variable from your first query and use that for the update, or use a cursor, etc.

You could call it from an anonymous block as a test, and use dbms_output to show the old and new values; again, don't use dbms_output in production code, only for debugging:

```
SET serveroutput ON
DECLARE
  l_customer_id sales.customer_id%type;
  l_product_id sales.product_id%type;
  l_new_quantity sales.quantity%type;
  l_old_quantity sales.quantity%type;
BEGIN
  l_customer_id := 5;
  l_product_id := 4;
  l_new_quantity := 200; 
  update_sales(l_customer_id, l_product_id, l_new_quantity, l_old_quantity);

  dbms_output.put_line('Quantity changed from ' || l_old_quantity
    || ' to ' || l_new_quantity
    || ' (' || to_char(l_new_quantity - l_old_quantity, 'FMS999') || ')');
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Quantity changed from 6 to 200 (+194)
```

You can call this from an application, using bind variables, in a similar way, and have the application display the values.

Note that I haven't committed or rolled back the changes, and another session trying to call the procedure with the same values will block until I do; but will then see the new value (200) when it does run. I also haven't done any validation or exception handling in the procedure, so the caller needs to do both.

You *could* make this a function that returns the old value instead of using an OUT parameter, but you'd need to call it in a similar way, and generally people don't expect functions to change anything - just to return the current state. But if this is really how you want to do it, you need to modify the declaration to have a return type and local variable; select the old value into that local variable; and then return that too:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sales
( 
  p_customer_id IN sales.customer_id%type,
  p_product_id IN sales.product_id%type,
  p_new_quantity IN sales.quantity%type
)
RETURN sales.quantity%type
AS
  l_old_quantity sales.quantity%type;
BEGIN
  SELECT quantity
  INTO l_old_quantity
  FROM sales
  WHERE customer_id = p_customer_id
  AND product_id = p_product_id;

  UPDATE sales
  SET quantity = p_new_quantity
  WHERE customer_id = p_customer_id
  AND product_id = p_product_id;

  RETURN l_old_quantity;
END;
/
```

You still have to call it from a PL/SQL context (or something like a JDBC callable statement):

```
DECLARE
  l_old_quantity sales.quantity%type;
BEGIN
  l_old_quantity := update_sales(5, 4, 200);
  dbms_output.put_line('Quantity was ' || l_old_quantity);
END;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Quantity was 6
```

You can't call it from plain SQL because it is doing a DML operation:

```
select update_sales(5, 4, 200) from dual;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query 
ORA-06512: at "MY_SCHEMA.UPDATE_SALES", line 17
14551. 00000 -  "cannot perform a DML operation inside a query "
*Cause:    DML operation like insert, update, delete or select-for-update
           cannot be performed inside a query or under a PDML slave.
*Action:   Ensure that the offending DML operation is not performed or
           use an autonomous transaction to perform the DML operation within
           the query or PDML slave.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you r solution .. If I want to use 'function' istead of procedure , would it be okay to replace the procedure word with function and all other lines would be the same? more about function is here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/plsql_functions.htm
Please advice

Comment: @Chaz - not quite; a function returns something, a procedure doesn't; so you would remove the OUT parameter and have a `return number` instead. You'd also need a local variable to select the old value into, and you'd also return that local variable. But a procedure is more appropriate here. I'm still not sure why you want a function for this.

Comment: I need a function here for work purposes.. can you please update the code to function instead of procedure.. it would be a huge favor .. Thanks in advace

Comment: @Chaz - OK, I've added a function version, but I'd still recommend using the procedure approach.

Comment: is there a way to return the new quantity also and the customer id as well? I tried to return it but failed. your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You can only return one value from a function. It doesn't have to be a scalar type though. It would be easier to have two OUT parameters in a procedure. But... you're passing in the customer ID, why do you need to get it back?

Comment: I need to print out the total quantity for the customer  before and after the update.. sadly returning only one value wont be helpful much .. can you help please?

Comment: You can have additional OUT parameters in a function, but why would you when you could just use a procedure and have as many out parameters are needed? Using a Function with extra OUT parameters is not normal practice and would be confusing when it comes to maintaining it in the future. You keep saying you need to use a function - why? "Work purposes" is not enough of a reason, IMHO. If the calling code can handle a function, it can handle a procedure just as easily!

Comment: I agree, and I'd kind of intentionally avoided saying you can have a function with OUT parameters, because it isn't a pattern a really want to promote to someone learning about functions, or going into non-scalar return types. I'm also unclear how "work purposes" ties in with 'printing' values, especially with dbms_output, or with "more knowledge in functions"; and why you need to return a value you have to already know for the IN parameter. The whole thing seems confused...

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your question is that you want to automatically update the quantity of the customer 5 to 200 whenever a new record is inserted in the SALES Table.

Trigger Code:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER quantity_change 
before insert on sales
for each row
WHEN (NEW.customer_id > 0)
DECLARE
var number;
BEGIN
 var:=update_sales(:new.customer_id,:new.quantity);
 :new.quantity:=var;
END;
```

Function Code:-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_sales(CUSTOMER_ID NUMBER,ORIG_QUANT NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS RETURNVALUE NUMBER;
BEGIN
  IF customer_id = 5 THEN
    returnvalue:=200;
    RETURN returnvalue;
  ELSE
  returnvalue:= orig_quant;
  RETURN returnvalue;
  END IF;   
END;
```

Sorry if I understood it otherwise.

Regards
Andy

Comment: Thanks but what I want is to enable the user to enter a customer id and update the quantity to a new value and show an output of the customer id and the old quantity value and the new value.. can you please update the code to match what I want? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To update a table you could use for example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Updatesales( 
    xCustomer_ID IN Table1.custumerId%TYPE, 
        xProduct_ID IN Table1.productId%TYPE,
    xQuantity IN Table1.quantity%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
        UPDATE  sales
    SET     quantity = xQuantity
    WHERE   customer_id = xCustomer_ID;

        COMMIT;
END;
/
```

To call this procedure you use: 
`Updatesales(4, 25, 100);`

Comment: That doesn't return the previous quantity value, which seems to be partly what the OP wants. Though it's pretty unclear what the underlying requirements are. (It's also not usually a good idea to commit inside a procedure, the caller should do that).

Comment: I do not agree on the `commit` part. If you have a procedure that is called from multiple locations, then you can better use the `commit` in one place. If you have a big database and you miss a commit somewhere in something that calls a procedure it is harder to find the problem.

Comment: Until you have another procedure that makes some other change, then calls this one, and then does more work of its own which gets an error. If that rolls back then you've lost atomicity as this change and anything before it is already committed, leaving your data in an strange state. And the calling procedure might not be expecting it. I'd argue that's going to be harder to track down. If the application controls commit/rollback at the highest level then you avoid the problem. ([It's not just me](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1519405621318#9903839346165))

Answer (score 0):

So what now I have done is I am calling a function from a procedure (created procedure as I as was not able to print all of the three values ), have made some assumptions from my side.

```
create or replace FUNCTION QUANTITY_CHANGE_NEW (CUSTOMER NUMBER, QUANT NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER 
IS PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
old_quantity NUMBER;
BEGIN
select quantity into old_quantity from sales where customer_id=customer and rownum=1;
update sales set quantity=quant where customer_id= customer;
COMMIT;
RETURN old_quantity;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE1(customer IN NUMBER, new_quantity IN NUMBER) IS 
var1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Customer Id is ' || customer);
var1 := QUANTITY_CHANGE_NEW(customer,new_quantity);
dbms_output.put_line('old quantity is '|| var1);
dbms_output.put_line('New quantity is '|| new_quantity);
END;
```

Regards
Andy